# How to interact between different panels?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach, panel

I need to make different TextBoxes interact between each other, even though they are in different panels, identified by different names in a foreach code.

I am making a Wordle game in Windows Forms. I have 5 different textBoxes, each one with its own code. I want to have 5 groups of 5 textBoxes (25 textBoxes in total), each group having the same code, but executed only when they are enabled. I enable each group one by one with a button, representing the different attempts in the game. For avoiding copy-pasting all my code 5 times, I put the TextBoxes in different panels. The first TextBox of each group goes in a panel, the second one in another and so on. I the use the following code:

```
foreach(TextBox name in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (name.Enabled == true)
    {
        //Code goes here
    }
}
```

My problem is that one of my TextBoxes need to interact with the ones that are before it, with this code for example:

```
if (textBox3 == textBox1 && textBox3 == textBox2)
{
    //Something happens
}
```

As I said before, textBox1, textBox2, and textBox3 are in different panels, and I don´t know how I can make them interact with each other like in the code above, while keeping the for each function. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use different panels. Say you have textboxes:

```
textBoxGroup1_Box1, textBoxGroup1_Box2... textBoxGroup5_Box1
```

You can put these into lists or arrays for organization:

```
var group1 = new []{
    textBoxGroup1_Box1, 
    textBoxGroup1_Box2, 
    textBoxGroup1_Box3,
    textBoxGroup1_Box4,
    textBoxGroup1_Box5};
...
```

This give you a way to iterate over all boxes without needing any extra panels.You can also put all the groups into a common list:

```
var groups = new []{ group1, group2, group3, group4, group5};
```

You can also use the `.Tag` property to an object to help you keep track of what box is what. For example:

```
public class TextboxId{
    public int Group {get; init;}
    public int Num { get; init;}
    public TextboxId(int group, int num) => (Group, Num ) = (group, num);
}
...
textBoxGroup1_Box1.Tag = new TextboxId(1, 1);
textBoxGroup1_Box2.Tag = new TextboxId(1, 2);
...
public void SomeMethod(TextBox tb){
    if( tb.Tag is TextBoxId id){
        var group = id.Group;
        var num = id.Num;
        if(group > 1){
            var boxInPreviousGroupWithSameNum = groups[group-1][num]; 
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

That should give you enough tools to implement whatever logic you want. Keep in mind that for more complicated behavior and UIs you would likely want to separate the logic from the UI as much as possible, and likely also to create your own user controls to make it easier to combine components in a flexible way.